# how sluggify a model with cviebrock slugs laravel

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5, slug

I just ran into a simple problem. 
I just installed [this package](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) and I wish to sluggify the entire model.

I have upgraded m model definition as instructed:

```
protected $sluggable = array(
    'build_from' => 'fullname',
    'save_to'    => 'slug',
);


 public function getFullnameAttribute()
{
    return $this->firstnames . '-' . $this->surname;
}
```

But now I am lost...

how to sluggify all the records in my table?

Comment: Read closer: "`build_from` This is the field *or array* of fields from which to build the slug". You should just be able to pass an array. like: `'build_from' => array('fullname', 'foo', 'bar')`

Comment: You can write a seeder to sluggify the records.

Comment: @Anatoliy - I know, but I have no clue how to do it. I have c. 1500 authors. I can sluggify them one-by-one by editing each record. I  just don't know how to write a good code to do all the records at once.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know. 
As the package's author wrote in readme.md, each record can be reslugged on save.

So I came op with this crude but working solution:

in my index method:

```
$object = Author::get();

foreach($object as $o)
{
$o->save();
}
```